# Antd Horizontal Menu Bar

Tags: css, menu, antd, responsiveness

I am using menu component from antd, [See Example 1 from the site](https://ant.design/components/menu/). The code can also be seen from [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/86ncd?file=/index.js). As seen from the code, the menu items are responsive. But I copied the exact same code, but it is not responsive.
Why is that so?

Comment: Share your code in sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this Into your html (or php) file?

meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,       initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

Comment: Yes, it is in my index.html. But this menu code is in a js file. I hope it is not a problem

Comment: I dont think so but maybe you can try to add the js code into your html file?